# sql server how long SELECT waits before deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock, sql-server-2019

I am doing a concurrency test in sql server 2019, I have SQLTest tool that runs concurrent queries, in my test I am using one single SELECT query (star schema) and on SSMS I have while loop that updates fact table records. while running both process I am seeing some of the threads/queries cancelled because of deadlock, which is expected but the option that I am looking or is there a possibility to add a wait time on my select before deadlock? in other words how much time SQL server waits before it creates deadlock error.

In this case I know constant updates are happening but we know that updates are for a fewer seconds so if SQL server can wait for some seconds before creating deadlock.

any suggestions or thoughts ?

Comment: Five seconds, I believe.

Comment: If a deadlock occurs, wait longer doesn't help you - that's basically the definition of a deadlock.

Comment: If you are using 2019, then why did you tag 2012?

Answer (score 1):

> is there a possibility to add a wait time on my select before deadlock?

No. It would make no sense.

A deadlock is defined as a dead end of locking, which will not, under no circumstrances, be fixed by simply waiting. One of the sides has to cancel.

I.e. 
Tx1 has lock on table a, waits for lock on table b
Tx2 has lock on table b, waitf for lock on table a

Normally SQL Server waits (timeout) and cancels. In this case the deadlock detection steps up and realizes that no, unless a side is thrown out there is no way this gets resolved, so - it cancels one side. There is no waiting, because this is actually a programming bug. No joke.

Up there, Tx2 should FIRST ask for a lock on table a. It is good practice to get locks in a transaction in a defined order so this does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing up your testing strategy a little.

Within your test harness, I would [`SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW;`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-deadlock-priority-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), so that when a deadlock is detected, your testing process voluntarily takes one for the team, allows itself to become the deadlock victim, and allows the conflicting process to continue.

Then, wrap the testing script in a [`TRY...CATCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). In the `CATCH` clause, check to see if the cause of the error is a deadlock (error code 1205), and if it is, retry your test. It's probably a good idea to also build a incremental counter into that so that you don't end up in an infinite deadlock loop.